# Beamer multiple note pages for one slide

Tags: beamer, notes

in my Beamer document I use \setbeamertemplate{note page}[plain] to create a page with additional informations about the slide for my handouts.

```
\begin{frame}{test}
    some text or figure
\note{discription in handout}
\end{frame}
```

This is a perfect solution for short Informations. Now, I have a slide which need more than one page of additional informations to explain. How can I create additional note pages?

```
\begin{frame}
    \note{
        more Infomations
    }
\end{frame}
```

will add an empty page (both in handout and non handout mode).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What about repeating the display frame (so nothing changes for the viewers) and adding another page of notices?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create multiple note pages per frame, by using overlay arguments:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeameroption{show notes}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    test
    \note<1>{information}
  \note<2>{more information}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. Unfortunately this only work in non handout mode.  If I set my Presentation in handout it puts the two note into one (informationmore information). Is there a way to force one this slide to be non handout mode?

Comment: @Nobody-86 To include it also in handout mode: ` \note<2|handout:2>{more information}`

Comment: Perfect! Thjs is exactly what I've been looking for. Many thanks!